# How to update eclipse indigo to eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

On Ubuntu I am trying to update Eclipse Indigo to Eclipse Luna. I followed the instructions given [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F), but when I go to 'Help > Check for Updates' I am not sure what to select and what not, and when I have selected what I think might be correct I get the following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Equinox p2 RCP Management Facilities Source 1.2.0.v20140523-0116 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.source.feature.group 1.2.0.v20140523-0116)
  Software being installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.M20120208-0800 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.2.M20120208-0800)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Provisioning Platform Update Support 1.0.200.v20110815-1419 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 1.0.200.v20110815-1419)
    Equinox Provisioning Platform Update Support 1.0.200.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 1.0.200.dist)
    Equinox Provisioning Platform Update Support 1.0.200.v20110502-1955 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 1.0.200.v20110502-1955)
    Equinox Provisioning Platform Update Support 1.0.300.v20140407-1803 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 1.0.300.v20140407-1803)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 RCP Management Facilities 1.0.1.v20110906-1605-782EqBqNKGVkiV-PUsgz-uny4gqO (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.v20110906-1605-782EqBqNKGVkiV-PUsgz-uny4gqO)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk [1.0.200.v20110815-1419]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2, minimal support for RCP applications 1.2.0.v20140523-0116 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v20140523-0116)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk [1.0.300.v20140407-1803]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 RCP Management Facilities Source 1.2.0.v20140523-0116 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.source.feature.group 1.2.0.v20140523-0116)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group [1.2.0.v20140523-0116]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Provisioning for IDEs. 2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bk8pYWZz0qUTX5I15GZWwbXkrl (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bk8pYWZz0qUTX5I15GZWwbXkrl)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.feature.group [1.0.1.v20110906-1605-782EqBqNKGVkiV-PUsgz-uny4gqO]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.M20120208-0800 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.2.M20120208-0800)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bk8pYWZz0qUTX5I15GZWwbXkrl]
```

The selection is given in the following image:

[image]

How can I update to Eclipse Luna?

Answer (score 1):

Just download new Eclipse Luna, remove Indigo and install Luna. Don't forget to save your projects so they won't be removed. Check for updates will check for Indigo updates, not Eclipse updates.

Comment: How to best download and install Luna? Is there a simple install command?

Comment: You need only to download it from official web-site and unzip it in any directory you want. Word install isn't too correct in this case.